# Get only meet records in SQL

Tags: sql

I have two column one with ID and Type. In ID there are repetitive numbers and in Type "NA", "Cont" and "Dis".

My need is get count of records where Type not equal to "NA" and also if "Dis" found then stop counting the below records.

[image]

You can see the attachment where total records are 12 including all type. But after removing NA count is 11 but on 7th rows type is "Dis" , so it will ignore all below records and output s/b 6 only.

Query:

```
Select A.ps_indv_id
     , A.Continue
from ( Select A.ps_indv_id
            , A.Continue 
            , A.[Row ID] 
       from [dbo].[DVT_Persist_Claims] A ) A
left join (Select A.ps_indv_id
                , Min(A.[Row ID])[Row ID]
           from (Select A.ps_indv_id
                      , A.Continue
                      , A.[Row ID] 
                 from [dbo].[DVT_Persist_Claims] A ) A
           where A.Continue = 'Discontinue'
           group by A.ps_indv_id ) B
   on A.ps_indv_id = B.ps_indv_id
where A.[Row ID] < B.[Row ID]
```

Example :

```
ps_indv_id        Type   Record No.
848803003283483   NA      1
848803003283483   Cont    2
848803003283483   Cont    3
848803003283483   Cont    4
848803003283483   Cont    5
848803003283483   Cont    6
848803003283483   Cont    7
848803003283483   Dis     8
848803003283483   Dis     9
848803003283483   Cont   10
848803003283483   Cont   11
848803003283483   Cont   12
```

Comment: what dbms are you using?

Comment: Is "Record No." in your table, or it is derived in some way?

Comment: Anything what you've tried so far? SO is not a code generator service, please show some effort. Also please take a look at [ask] in [help]

Comment: Hi Degan, Record no. is just for fyi only.. its not in DB.

Comment: OK, if Record No. is not a part of the db, then how is it determined?  What makes your Record No. = 10 "after" Record No. = 7?  I understand that you want 7, but do not want 10, however, other than Record No. they are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this the result you are looking for?

```
select t.type, count(t.type)
from table t
group by t.type
having t.record_no < (
     select Min(record_no)
     from table
     where Type = 'Dis'
     )
and t.type <> 'NA'
```

If record_no is derived, then let us know the rules for deriving it.

Comment: Hi Degan, Again i stuck. As i have multiple rows for ps_indv_id  which are different. So above query works for 1 ID(848803003283483) but when i try this query on my DB where multiple ID are there, then it takes only one min Record i.e. for First record set only.

Comment: ps_indv_id         Type Record No.
848803003283483 NA 1
848803003283483 Cont 2
848803003283483 Cont 3
848803003283483 Cont 4
848803003283483 Cont 5
848803003283483 Cont 6
848803003283483 Cont 7
848803003283483 Dis 8
848803003283483 Dis 9
848803003283483 Cont 10
848803003283483 Cont 11
848803003283483 Cont 12
848803003284019 NA 1
848803003284019 Cont 2
848803003284019 Cont 3
848803003284019 Dis 4
848803003284019 Dis 5
848803003284019 Dis 6
848803003285444 NA 1
848803003285444 Cont 2
848803003285444 Dis 3

Comment: Perhaps you can update the sample record set, show the SQL code that created the sample set, and let us know what you want different about the result?

Comment: Hi @Degan ,    ID Continue? Row ID
848803003285459 New 1
848803003285459 Cont 2
848803003285459 Cont 3
848803003285459 Dis 4
848803003285459 Cont 5
848803003285608 New 1
848803003285608 Cont 2
848803003285608 Cont 3
848803003285608 Cont 4
848803003285819 New 1
848803003285819 Cont 2
848803003285819 Dis 3
848803003285819 Cont 4
848803003285819 Dis 5
848803030014801 New 1
848803030014801 Cont 2
848803030014801 Cont 3
848803030014801 Cont 4
848803030018694 New 1
848803030018694 Cont 2
848803030018694 Cont 3
848803030018694 Cont 4

Comment: Here is the query :    Select
A.ps_indv_id,
A.Continue 
from (
Select A.ps_indv_id, A.Continue  , A.[Row ID]
from [dbo].[DVT_Persist_Claims] A 
)A 
left join 
(Select A.ps_indv_id, Min(A.[Row ID])[Row ID] from
(Select A.ps_indv_id , A.Continue, A.[Row ID] 
from [dbo].[DVT_Persist_Claims] A  
)A where A.Continue = 'Discontinue' group by A.ps_indv_id 
)B on A.ps_indv_id = B.ps_indv_id where A.[Row ID] < B.[Row ID]

Comment: But through this query i am able to pick all ID Where Continue = Dis for e.g 848803003285459 , On row ID 4 Dis found and it will pick all 1, 2, 3 records for this ID. But in Second example 848803003285608 there is no any Dis found and query not able to pick this ID also as in this ID all ID are in New and Continue state. So my requirement is to pick all records where New and Continue is there but if Dis found then just pick above records only.  Pls help me

Comment: so for me here is are the records which need to pick :   848803003285459 New 1
848803003285459 Cont 2
848803003285459 Cont 3
848803003285608 New 1
848803003285608 Cont 2
848803003285608 Cont 3
848803003285608 Cont 4
848803003285819 New 1
848803003285819 Cont 2
848803030014801 New 1
848803030014801 Cont 2
848803030014801 Cont 3
848803030014801 Cont 4
848803030018694 New 1
848803030018694 Cont 2
848803030018694 Cont 3
848803030018694 Cont 4

Comment: @Aditya, Your sample data has the three columns: ps_indv_id, Type, Record No.; your query selects two columns: A.ps_indv_id, A.Continue.  This does not match.  Since you ask, "then stop counting the below records" we need to see the query that derives, "Record No."

Comment: Record No. is nothing but derived column :  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A.ps_indv_id ORDER BY A.ps_indv_id [Record No.]

Comment: @Aditya, "Order by ps_indv_id" will not give you a consistent ordering over time when you have multiple records with the same ps_indv_id, so this seems like a dangerous strategy.  Do you have a column that has the last update date/time of the record?